# Calling ASP method inside javascript code

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

i wonder if there is any way to call an asp method that returns a string or something when you are in `<script></script>` tags.

Like this (it does not work):

```
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function isValid() {
        var required = "<%= callAspMethodThatReturnsSomething() %>";
    }
    </script>
```

any help with this? thx!

Comment: This _should_ work if the method is defined in the code behind. Can you explain _what exactly_ doesn't work?

Comment: When i run this code, then `required`gives me `null`. Actually the method is not in codebehind. I am working with masterpages and the method is in the masterpage. So i do `Master.Method()` in codebehind to get the method...

Comment: How does the final rendered HTML look like when you browse the source code?

Comment: it gives me nothing, the ASP code disappears in javascript like this: `var required = "";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are calling a method on the master page from the content page directly.

You can't do that - you need a reference to the strongly typed master page.

Try this (asp.net 4.0):

```
<%:((MasterPageClassName)Page.Master).callAspMethodThatReturnsSomething()%>
```

Or this (pre 4.0):

```
<%=((MasterPageClassName)Page.Master).callAspMethodThatReturnsSomething()%>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct way to call c# method like in example above. But you can send `$.ajax` request to the server, or even send postback using `_doPostBack(..,..)`

Comment: The code is within a server side code block `<%%>`, so it runs server side. Not sure what you are talking about.

Comment: @Oded: True, but seems @Ozkan want to execute c# method from client side and not just during page rendering.

Comment: not if he put the server side code in server side code blocks. I think he wants the return value (presumably a string) to be output to the javascript.

Comment: @Oded: Yeah, i see, seems your true. I just misunderstand question for first time. Thanks for pointing it out. +1 ;)

Answer (score 0):

<% callAspMethodThatReturnsSomething() %>

this method in <% %> will work before what you want to do ,it may looks like does not work

yet,you can create a new button on page ,make it unvisible and use it's click event like document.getElementById("<%=button1.ClientID%>").click()